# React - remove event listener (onmousedown -> onmousemove)

Tags: reactjs, onmousedown, onmousemove, removeeventlistener

I have element that can be stretched - when I drag .leftMove its change left position and width of parent, and when drag .rightMove it change width of parent.

The problem is that I can't remove event listener on mouseUp. It's still there, i manage to remove event on second mouse hover, but still it's huge problem that element accidentaly change size on first mouseover.

```
return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="leftMove" 
                onMouseDown={mouseDownLeft} 
                onMouseUp={MouseUp} 
                onMouseLeave={MouseUp}></div>
            <div className="rightMove"  
                onMouseDown={mouseDownRight} 
                onMouseUp={MouseUp} 
                onMouseLeave={MouseUp}>
            </div>
        </Fragment>)
```

```
const resize = (e) => {
        
        ...change width and position left...
        let thisone = e.target;
        thisone.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
        
        thisone.onmouseup = function() {
            console.log('removed');
            thisone.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false); 
        };

        thisone.onmouseleave = function() {
            console.log('removed by leave');
            thisone.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false); //working on leave and comeback second time
            thisone.removeEventListener("onmousedown", resize, false); 
        };
    };
```

```
const MouseUp = (e) => {
      
        e.target.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false); //not working at all

        //update global state, it's update elements I am changing width, leftpos

        setState(prevsetState => ({
            ...prevsetState,
            fromSetting: {
                ...prevsetState.fromSetting,
                mods: filteredDataSource
            }
        }));
  

    }

const mouseDownLeft = (e) => {
        //determining left right move
    
        e.target.addEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a mistake of mine. I listen to a parent element and try to resize it by child element and then remove event listener from child (but it was listening to parent)

```
const mouseDownRight = (e) => {

        console.log('downright');

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();

        //let grabbing = e.target.closest('.elementtoresize'); <-mistake

        let grabbing = e.target; // right element to listen to

        m_pos = e.clientX;

        exDirect = -1;
        grabbing.addEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
      
    }
```